# spec is_valid appears to not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an ActiveRecord model:

```
class Hotlink < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of :link

end
```

That i test with:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Hotlink do

  it "should require a name" do
    Hotlink.new.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should require a name 2" do 
    link1 = Hotlink.new
    link1.link = nil
    link1.should_not be_valid
  end 


  it "should require a name 3" do 
    link2 = Hotlink.new
    link2.link = nil
    link2.save
    link2.should_not be_valid
    link2.valid?.should be_false
  end 

end
```

All these tests fail. I'm confused? Should these not pass?

They fail with: expected valid? to return false, got true

In environments/test.r b I've turned off cache classing with no luck.

Edit: The following works. I'm even more confused now:

```
Hotlink.new().valid?.should != true
```

Edit: Source of problem found:

I have a controller spec that if I delete will make model specs pass. Why is this?

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + 'spec_helper'

describe HotlinksController do


  before :each do
   @current_user = mock_model(User, :id => 1)
   controller.stub!(:current_user).and_return(@current_user)
   controller.stub!(:login_required).and_return(:true)
  end


  fixtures :all
  render_views


  it "create action should redirect when model is valid" do
    Hotlink.any_instance.stubs(:valid?).returns(true)
    post :create
    response.should redirect_to(root_url)
  end


end
```

Comment: I just set up an empty rails app (3.0.4), added a migration, your specs, and your model, and the specs all passed. Is there anything you stripped out of the example that might be making the difference? What versions of rails and rspec do you have? Is your spec_helper the one generated by "rails generate rspec:install"?

Comment: spec_helper is the same as rails g rspec:install. Using rails 3.0.5 rspec 2.5.0. There was additional stuff in my model/spec but I've stripped it out so its exactly as above. Still doesn't work

Comment: @Iain I've done same as you and new blank rails project works fine. But when I add in controller specs, it fails. Modified question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pointing the finger at this line:

```
Hotlink.any_instance.stubs(:valid?).returns(true)
```

I'd love a proper fix, but when I bumped into something like this a while ago I found a way of testing the desired behaviour without the troublesome mock.

In this case, you might get away with something like (untested):

```
hotlink = Hotlink.new
Hotlink.stub(:new).and_return(hotlink)
hotlink.stub(:valid?).and_return(true)
```

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that would be the issue. But how do I get round it. I don't want to just remove controller specs. If I remove "any_instance" then the controller spec fails as it renders a 200 instead of a redirect

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a suggested approach. To some extent, this stuff is why I don't like controller specs.

Comment: Thanks. I'm beginning to not like controller specs either.